# how to get value from array like [{"id":"3","value":"12345"},{"id":"4","value":"ABCDEFG1"},{"id":"5","value":"12"}]

Tags: php, html, json, laravel

```
<?php $temp_hsn= getPart($d->product_id)->custom_field; ?>

<td class="text-Left cname"><?php echo $temp_hsn; ?></td>
```

getting below value by above code

```
[{"id":"3","value":"12345"},{"id":"4","value":"ABCDEFG1"},{"id":"5","value":"12"}]
[{"id":"3","value":"1234567"},{"id":"4","value":"ABCDEFG12"},{"id":"5","value":"12"}]
[{"id":"3","value":"12345678"},{"id":"4","value":"ABCDEFG123"},{"id":"5","value":"12"}]
[{"id":"3","value":"jhgj31323n"},{"id":"4","value":""},{"id":"5","value":"18"},{"id":"8","value":""}]
```

but I want to display the value of "id":"4" only

[image]

Comment: How come you get a string while you are rendering the data in `td` tag? A screenshot would be better.

Comment: These appear to be several JSON-encoded arrays output after another - so you can not use json_decode on the whole thing, you will have to take this apart into the individual "lines" first. Unless you can still change how that data gets stored in the first place - it should rather be an array of arrays, encode as JSON in one go.

Comment: "by above code" - what does that mean? Where's the code?

Comment: _"getting below value by above code"_ - that appears to be the column content from _multiple_ records in your database, how did those get smushed together? The individual values appear to be valid JSON - so _those_ could easily be decoded, and then you just have to pick the data you want out of the resulting PHP data structure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: <?php $temp_hsn= getPart($d->product_id)->custom_field; ?>
<td class="text-Left cname"><?php echo $temp_hsn; ?></td>

result is
[{"id":"3","value":"12345"},{"id":"4","value":"ABCDEFG1"},{"id":"5","value":"12"}]
but I need only the value of "id":"4" i.e. ABCDEFG1

then changed to
<?php $temp_hsn = collect(json_decode(getPart($d->product_id)->custom_field))->where('id', 4); ?>
<td class="text-left cname"><?php echo $temp_hsn; ?> </td>

and result is
{"1":{"id":"4","value":"ABCDEFG1"}}
but I need only the value of "id":"4" i.e. ABCDEFG1

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't put important information (like the code involved) in the comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now code is like this

```
$temp_hsn = collect(json_decode(getPart($d->product_id)->custom_field))->where('id', 4);
echo substr($temp_hsn, 24, -3);
```

now output is ABCDEFG1.
[image]